# checking for fields which are empty or not in js

Tags: javascript

I have two text box and one dropdown in my datatable.
I need to set these 3 field as required while updating data table.
None of this 3 fields should be empty.
I tried using the following code,

```
if(!temp_name  && !com_name && !name) {
                $('#temp_'+index).attr('required','true');
                $('#temp_'+index).attr('aria-required','true');
                $('#com_'+index).attr('required','true');
                $('#com_'+index).attr('aria-required','true');
                $('#name_'+index).attr('required','true');
                $('#name_'+index).attr('aria-required','true'); 
 }
```

The above code is not working properly. it shows required when 3 fields are empty at time.
I have done something which is correctly working.

I have the following code,

```
            var r = confirm("Are you sure want to Update ?");
            var index = $(this).attr('index');
            var temp_name = $('#temp_'+index).val();
            var com_name = $('#com_'+index).val();
            var name = $('#name_'+index).val();
            if (r == true) {
                if(!temp_name && !com_name && !name) {
                    $('#temp_'+index).attr('required','true');
                    $('#temp_'+index).attr('aria-required','true');
                    $('#com_'+index).attr('required','true');
                    $('#com_'+index).attr('aria-required','true');
                    $('#name_'+index).attr('required','true');
                    $('#name_'+index).attr('aria-required','true');         
                }else if(!temp_name && !com_name){                      
                    $('#temp_'+index).attr('required','true');
                    $('#temp_'+index).attr('aria-required','true');
                    $('#com_'+index).attr('required','true');
                    $('#com_'+index).attr('aria-required','true');
                }else if(!temp_name && !name){                  
                    $('#temp_'+index).attr('required','true');
                    $('#temp_'+index).attr('aria-required','true'); 
                    $('#name_'+index).attr('required','true');
                    $('#name_'+index).attr('aria-required','true');         
                }else if(!com_name && !name){
                    $('#com_'+index).attr('required','true');
                    $('#com_'+index).attr('aria-required','true');
                    $('#name_'+index).attr('required','true');
                    $('#name_'+index).attr('aria-required','true');    

                }else if(!temp_name){
                    $('#temp_'+index).attr('required','true');
                    $('#temp_'+index).attr('aria-required','true'); 

                }else if(!com_name){
                    $('#com_'+index).attr('required','true');
                    $('#com_'+index).attr('aria-required','true');

                }else if(!name){
                    $('#name_'+index).attr('required','true');
                    $('#name_'+index).attr('aria-required','true');    

                }
                else{
                  ///
                }
```

Is there any better way to do the same.
Any suggestions?

Comment: you should use OR statement not AND.

Answer (score 0):

just do them one at a time?

```
var fail = false;
if(!temp_name){
     $('#temp_'+index).attr('required','true');
     $('#temp_'+index).attr('aria-required','true'); 
     fail = true;
}
if(!com_name){
     $('#com_'+index).attr('required','true');
     $('#com_'+index).attr('aria-required','true');
     fail = true;
}
if(!name){
     $('#name_'+index).attr('required','true');
     $('#name_'+index).attr('aria-required','true');  
     fail = true;  
}
if (fail) {
    //do else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think y should use this

[Validate Js](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(temp_name != "" && temp_name != NULL){
     $('#temp_'+index).attr('required','true');
     $('#temp_'+index).attr('aria-required','true'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var r = confirm("Are you sure want to Update ?");
        var index = $(this).attr('index');
        var temp_name = $('#temp_'+index).val();
        var com_name = $('#com_'+index).val();
        var name = $('#name_'+index).val();
        if (r == true) {
         $('#temp_'+index).attr('required',!temp_name);
         $('#temp_'+index).attr('aria-required',!temp_name);
         $('#com_'+index).attr('required',!com_name);
         $('#com_'+index).attr('aria-required',!com_name);
         $('#name_'+index).attr('required',!name );
         $('#name_'+index).attr('aria-required',!name );  
}
```